# join two dataframes to closest record

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, outer-join

Suppose I have two dataframes. The first dataframe is the famous iris dataset:

```
> data(iris)
> print(iris)
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
.... (150 observations)
```

The second dataset contains means for each attribute:

```
library(dplyr)
iris.means <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length),
            Sepal.Width = mean(Sepal.Width),
            Petal.Length = mean(Petal.Length),
            Petal.Width = mean(Petal.Width))

> print(iris.means)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa             5.01        3.43         1.46       0.246
2 versicolor         5.94        2.77         4.26       1.33 
3 virginica          6.59        2.97         5.55       2.03
```

Is there an elegant way to (left outer) join the iris dataframe to the means, where we match against the attributes of the closest record?

The obvious answer is:

1. Crossjoin of the two dataframes.
2. Groupwise rank, where the group is the iris record. The rank would be in ascending order of the absolute difference between the actual values and the means for each species.
3. Select the top rank for each group.

Like this:

```
iris <- iris %>% mutate(id = row_number())

iris.means <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(Sepal.Length.Mean = mean(Sepal.Length),
            Sepal.Width.Mean = mean(Sepal.Width),
            Petal.Length.Mean = mean(Petal.Length),
            Petal.Width.Mean = mean(Petal.Width))

names(iris.means)[names(iris.means) == "Species"] <- "Species.Mean"

iris.crossjoin <- merge(iris, iris.means, all=TRUE)
```

The crossjoined dataset has three records for each of the original iris records. We started off with 150 records; we now have 450:

```
> arrange(iris.crossjoin, id)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species id Species.Mean Sepal.Length.Mean Sepal.Width.Mean Petal.Length.Mean Petal.Width.Mean
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  1       setosa             5.006            3.428             1.462            0.246
2           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  1   versicolor             5.936            2.770             4.260            1.326
3           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  1    virginica             6.588            2.974             5.552            2.026
4           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  2       setosa             5.006            3.428             1.462            0.246
5           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  2   versicolor             5.936            2.770             4.260            1.326
6           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  2    virginica             6.588            2.974             5.552            2.026
.... (450 observations)
```

We calculate the aggregated distance between each record in the iris dataset and the means for each species. As @AEF points out in the comments below, this is the Manhattan distance:

```
iris.crossjoin <- iris.crossjoin %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Length.Delta = abs(Sepal.Length.Mean - Sepal.Length),
         Sepal.Width.Delta = abs(Sepal.Width.Mean - Sepal.Width),
         Petal.Length.Delta = abs(Petal.Length.Mean - Petal.Length),
         Petal.Width.Delta = abs(Petal.Width.Mean - Petal.Width),
         Delta.Sum = Sepal.Length.Delta + Sepal.Width.Delta + Petal.Length.Delta + Petal.Width.Delta)
```

We can then filter the records from the crossjoined datasets that have the closest distance to a mean:

```
iris.crossjoin <- iris.crossjoin %>% arrange(id, Delta.Sum) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(Delta.Sum, ties.method = "first"),
         correct = Species == Species.Mean) %>%
  filter(rank == 1)
```

The output would look something like this:

```
> iris.crossjoin[c('id', 'Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Species', 'Species.Mean', 'correct')]

     id Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species Species.Mean correct
1     1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa       setosa    TRUE
2     2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa       setosa    TRUE
...
52   52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor   versicolor    TRUE
53   53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor    virginica   FALSE
54   54          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor   versicolor    TRUE
...
```

The `Species` column is the actual value and `Species.Mean` is the predicted column, based on Manhattan distance to the closest species mean.

Is there a better way to do this? Crossjoin is fine for a small dataset but seems like an anti-pattern at scale.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be solved elegantly within the tidyverse. I would probably build a kd-tree for the group-means (OK, for only 4 groups this is a bit of overkill) and then match each point of the original dataset to the closest mean. `RANN::nn2` has already implemented that process. However it uses euclidian distance instead of manhattan distance like in your example (which does not run btw)

Comment: `iris.means` is grouped by `Species` but in the crossjoin you merged without considering `Species`. Is this intended? Furthermore, please, can you show the desired result for the `iris` dataset -Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe: I added an example of the expected output and fixed the example code so it works. I made a silly cut & paste error.

Comment: @AEF: thanks for the nearest neighbor recommendation. That's very helpful. I fixed the code so it now runs - sorry for that.